# How to put a condition in a handler?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

I have two buttons **"Button-1"** and **"Button-2"**, these buttons contain a KeyboardButtonRequestChat object with different criteria. There are also 2 handlers, they receive channel IDs via Chat_shared after the button is clicked. However, I don't understand how to create a condition where pressing "Button-1" will call the first handler, and pressing "Button-2" will call another handler?

Usually I insert a condition for checking the message **text: message.text == "Button-1"**, but in this case, after clicking the button, the text is not sent to the chat.

I would be grateful for any ideas.)

**Buttons:**

```
@dp.message(lambda message: message.text == "Buttons")
async def configure_source_channels(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_states[user_id] = UserStates.SOURCE_CHANNELS
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
        [KeyboardButton(text="button-1", request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestChat(
            request_id=1,
            user_is_bot=False,
            chat_is_channel=True,
            chat_is_forum=False
        ))],
        [KeyboardButton(text="button-2", request_chat=KeyboardButtonRequestChat(
            request_id=2,
            user_is_bot=True,
            chat_is_channel=False,
            chat_is_forum=False
        ))],
])
```

**Handlers:**

```
@dp.message(F.chat)
async def button1(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id

@dp.message(F.chat)
async def button2(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **F.content_type** filter in decorator, in your case it's:

```
@dp.message(F.content_type == "chat_shared")
async def button1(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id

@dp.message(F.content_type == "chat_shared")
async def button2(msg: Message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_info = msg.chat_shared.chat_id
```